# Silverstripe Customising the behaviour of GridFieldExportButton

Tags: php, silverstripe

In Silverstripe 3.3.1 GridFieldExportButton seems impossible to override. In this case I am using userforms and I need to take control of functions in GridFieldExportButton like generateExportFileData() in order to alter certain behaviours like using field labels as field names in the csv and including 
 tags.

I have tried extending directly

```
class SubmissionExportButton extends GridFieldExportButton
```

Through _config.php

```
Object::add_extension('GridFieldExportButton', 'SubmissionExportButton');

class SubmissionExportButton extends Extension{}
```

and Through Injector.

```
class SubmissionExportButton extends GridFieldExportButton{}

Injector:
  GridFieldExportButton:
    class: SubmissionExportButton
```

I have even attempted to completely replace the class and extend UserDefinedForm but his had some unexpected results. Better to simply take control of the class in question, but what is the right procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy the approach taken within https://github.com/axyr/silverstripe-phpexcel to create a new component and unregister the default one and register this instead.

Comment: Is that really what that is doing? It looks to me like we are simply extending the class and then instantiating it. Like, it's a sub class with a diffrent name. The advantage of the injector approach is that it really extends the behaviour of the existing class under the same name meaning that I can alter the behviour without worring about where the instances might be created.

Comment: I (and the upvoter) think so :)  install the module along with userforms, edit the module to do what you want...change its buttons behavior... but if I'm wrong maybe edit your question to make it clearer or just wait for other answers (as i may have just misunderstood)

Comment: Well, part of the problem here is that UserDefinedForm adds all it's fields to the CMS layout using beforeUpdateCMSFields(). It's a confusing arrangement because I was unsure how to override it. In the end I had to nearly duplicate that code (found in /userforms/code/model/UserDefinedForm.php in the GetCMSFields() function) to get the thing to work. I am still unclear on the order of execution and I'm unhappy about that.

Comment: Still that is a whole other discussion. So as far as this question goes I think that this answer is basically correct in that the the class has to be replaced since it does not appear possible to inject behaviour into it. I am hoping though for a clearer explanation of why none of the standard extension procedures work.

Answer (score 0):

Injector should be perfectly suited for this, so just to double check your process:

**~/mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
Injector:
  GridFieldExportButton:
    class: SubmissionExportButton
```

**~/mysite/code/SubmissionExportButton.php**

```
class SubmissionExportButton extends GridFieldExportButton
{
    public function generateExportFileData($gridField)
    {
        // override here, retain return types!
    }
    // etc...
}
```

**Then:**

1. run `~/dev/build/?flush`
2. run `~/admin/pages/?flush`

I have sometimes had issues that the CMS cache does not clear in a manner consistent with the front-end flush, but I've definitely had to run it to get certain tweaks working in the past. I've even had to flush the CMS multiple times, but that's generally when I've reached `$utter_frustration_point` or 3am in the morning :P

I also checked `silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms` just to be sure they are not already overriding `GridFieldExportButton` - seems not, so good luck, I hope this helps :)